# How to add printer with app through WiFi in android?

Tags: android

In my app I want to link a WiFi printer with my app to print the bill....

Also, how would I print my data in bill format on button click??

I want to add textview in listview with static values and with fetch from database...

```
userdetail=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUserOrder);
    userdetail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HashSet<String> listToSet = new HashSet<String>(selected);
            List<String> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(User_MainOptions_List.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_order_detail, null);
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Your Order Detail");

            ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewUserOrderDetail);
            TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTotalPrice);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            date.setText("Date : "+today.monthDay+"/"+today.month+"/"+today.year);
            time.setText("Time : "+today.format("%k:%M:%S"));

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

            for(int i=0;i<listWithoutDuplicates.size();i++)
            {
                String s=listWithoutDuplicates.get(i);
                /*if (null != s && s.length() > 0 )
                {
                    int endIndex = s.lastIndexOf("  :");
                    if (endIndex != -1)  
                    {
                        String newstr = s.substring(0, endIndex);
                        //discount=database.getSubCategoryDiscount(newstr);
                    }

                }*/  
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile(":(.+?)/").matcher(s);
                while(m.find()) {
                    price = m.group(1);
                }
                a=Integer.parseInt(price);
                total=total+a;
                adapter.add(s/*+"  (Discount:"+discount+"%)"*/);
            }
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            if(total==0)
            {
                tv.setText("Order Not Posted");
            }
            else
            {
                tv.setText("Total Amount is :"+Integer.toString(total)+" "+MainActivity.currency);
                tv.setSelected(true);
                tv.setSingleLine();
                tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
                tv.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
            }
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

I want to print the details I get from this code with a WIFI printer on button click....